# Angular: FormArray setting validators

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have a form array where i am dynamically adding prime-ng checkbox elements too. I want the form to be valid only if at least one of the checkboxes are selected. However my code is not functioning it let's the user save without checking any boxes.

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="addSystemAlertForm">

            <div class="ui-grid-row">
                            <label for="systemAlertTypesIds"><span class="required">*</span>Select at least one</label><br>

                        <div   formArrayName="systemAlertTypesIds" *ngFor="let systemAlertType of systemAlertTypes; let i = index"><p-checkbox  formControlName="{{ i }}" [value]="systemAlertType.id" [(ngModel)]="selectedSystemAlertTypes" [label]="systemAlertType.name"></p-checkbox> <br/><br/></div> 

        </form>
```

.ts:

```
constructor( injector: Injector,private fb: FormBuilder, confirmationService: ConfirmationService) { 
    super(injector);
    this.addSystemAlertForm = this.fb.group({


      'systemAlertTypesIds' : new FormArray([])
     });

  }


  //this method gets called before the checkboxes get rendered on the dialog
  getSystemAlertTypes(){
  this.systemAlertTypes = [];


  this.mccSystemAlertService.getSystemAlertTypes().subscribe(val => {
      val.payload["systemAlertType"].map(function (reg) {
        this.systemAlertTypes.push(reg);

      }.bind(this))

      let systemAlertsFormArray = <FormArray>this.addSystemAlertForm.controls['systemAlertTypesIds'];
      systemAlertsFormArray.setValidators(Validators.required);
     this.systemAlertTypes.forEach(reg => systemAlertsFormArray.push(new FormControl()));

  });
}
```

Comment: why are you using `[(ngModel)]` with `formControlName` ?

Comment: I am adding to the vhevkboxes dynamically

Comment: i did not get your idea , can you explain to me what `[(ngModel)]="selectedSystemAlertTypes"` does exactly in your form ?

Comment: When i am showing the dialog for the user to edit the form i use the ngmodel to preselect some checkboxes.. showDialogToEdit(systemalert) {
    this.msgs = [];
    this.selectedSystemAlertTypes = systemalert.systemAlertTypeIds ? systemalert.systemAlertTypeIds.split(',').map(Number) : [];
    }